# IOS Sharing URL to Facebook doesn't show PreView

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, share

My app is developed with Xcode 6.1.1 and for IOS 8.+ IPhone.
I am adding the Share functionality for example on Facebook, and would like to have a URL. It works partially: text is shown, but the URL preview is not shown and doesn't appear later. Once posted on Facebook, URL preview is shown.

```
        NSString* newMessage = @"UCC Test";
        NSURL* newUrl =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/app/id378458261"];

           if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
        {
            SLComposeViewController *facebookSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                                   composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

            [facebookSheet setInitialText:newMessage];
            [facebookSheet addURL:newUrl];
            [callerView presentViewController:facebookSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
```

I have tried with UIActivityViewController; and get the same result. Posting directly on Facebook the URL works.

Any help or tip is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

For inviting users you can use the following code after adding the facebook-sdk

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"", @"name",
                               @"", @"caption",
                               @"", @"description",
                               @"http://itunes.apple.com/app/id378458261", @"link",

                               nil];

// Show the feed dialog
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:sharedFacebookHelper.session
                                       parameters:params
                                          handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)
 {
     if (error)
     {

     }
     else
     {
         if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted)
         {



         }
         else
         {
             // Handle the publish feed callback
             NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];

             if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"])
             {

             }
             else
             {

             }

                        }
     }
 }];
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunatly it does not help. I have noted that the URL preview comes but several second after the window has been displayed. Have you met such behaviour ?